# Are sockets communicating on the same PC that much slower than using shared memory?

Tags: windows, sockets, dll, shared-memory

I have a Windows DLL that provides video to an external application.  My main application creates each video frame and I use globally shared memory backed by the system page file to pass that frame to the DLL.  The video frame is subsequently retrieved by the external application and then displayed.  I do not own the external application, just the DLL it loads to get video from.  I am considering switching to a socket based approach to talk between my main application and the DLL and getting rid of the shared memory approach.  I do not like watching the "soft page faults" pile up as I repetitively invalidate the shared memory location each time I write a new video frame to it.  I believe that the soft page faults are harmless, just a side effect of the memory paging involved, but I would be more comfortable without it.

Since the video is being delivered at a frame rate of about 25 frames per second, I have approximately 1/25th of a second to transfer the frame.  The frames are never larger than 640 x 480 and they are compressed JPEG frames so they aren't very large at all, usually about 10,000 bytes.  So here's my question:

With an already open and persistent socket connection between two sockets on the same PC, will the time to transfer a video frame be significantly longer using a socket instead of a shared memory location?  Or at the O/S level is it just a fast memory write with some insignificant "window dressing" around it to support the socket communication?

Comment: You would have to profile each method to get an accurate on which is faster and by how much but I would think memory to be faster then over sockets. The page faults issue would be what I would look into IMO.

Comment: Note that you also have pipes as an option to send data back and forth. Local/loopback sockets are fast, but they are not really the best method of IPC in anyway other than if you are already feeling confortable with sockets and your code fits using sockets for the purpose very well. See other `IPC` options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RomanR.  I tried pipes once or twice in the past and ran into problems.  I forget exactly what happened but it had to do with lockups when reading/writing them.  I'll go look at that link you gave me now.  I'll probably give SendMessage()/WM_COPYDATA a try.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of using shared memory is avoiding memory copies from application to kernel buffers (and back on the receiving end) and getting rid of user to kernel mode switching via system calls. You still need synchronization between cooperating processes, but that could be done in userland avoiding the kernel. All this is far from trivial and few people get it right, but my point is that switching to sockets *will* make your system slower. By how much and if that is acceptable is for you to measure and judge.

There's another side to socket-based vs. shared memory-based setup - flexibility - with sockets it's easy to switch to a distributed setup. With networks getting faster and faster that's what might be in store for you down the road.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, shared memory would be faster as the socket communication adds a layer of indirection and instructions. Do you need backing for your shared memory? Windows allows shared memory without disk backing. I believe there's a way to keep the region from getting swapped as well, but don't know off-hand.